# WordPress: Issues with wp-includes/canonical.php Undefined Index in Host

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect, dns, undefined-index

Just had my server rebooted and now five errors, all related to canonical.php in the wp-includes folder show up:

```
[Sun Sep 22 19:55:37.037647 2019] [php7:notice] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: host in /www/webroot/cafed/wordpress/wp-includes/canonical.php on line 507
[Sun Sep 22 19:55:37.037679 2019] [php7:notice] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: host in /www/webroot/cafed/wordpress/wp-includes/canonical.php on line 508
[Sun Sep 22 19:55:37.037702 2019] [php7:notice] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: host in /www/webroot/cafed/wordpress/wp-includes/canonical.php on line 508
[Sun Sep 22 19:55:37.037708 2019] [php7:notice] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: host in /www/webroot/cafed/wordpress/wp-includes/canonical.php on line 509
[Sun Sep 22 19:55:37.037714 2019] [php7:notice] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: host in /www/webroot/cafed/wordpress/wp-includes/canonical.php on line 512
```

That seems to relate to this piece of code:

```
// Ignore differences in host capitalization, as this can lead to infinite redirects
// Only redirect no-www <=> yes-www
if ( strtolower( $original['host'] ) == strtolower( $redirect['host'] ) ||
    ( strtolower( $original['host'] ) != 'www.' . strtolower( $redirect['host'] ) && 'www.' . strtolower( $original['host'] ) != strtolower( $redirect['host'] ) ) ) {
    $redirect['host'] = $original['host'];
}

$compare_original = array( $original['host'], $original['path'] );
```

Seems to have something related to non-www vs www domains.

Any idea how to correct this?

Answer (score 5):

Yes this is regarding your domain. I suggest checking your wp_options table and confirming the 'home' and 'siteurl' option values are correct.

If they are correct then I would examine the htaccess file and confirm the rewrite module is correct per the [Codex](https://wordpress.org/support/article/htaccess/).

Answer (score 0):

For completeness: these errors were logged during an attack on my server.
The `fail2ban apache-noscript` jail handled them for me.

Answer (score 0):

What solved it for me after a migration and server name change from internal DNS to Domain name. Protocol was missing from wordpress database for ‘siteurl’ and ‘home’

Used MySQL to change these in wp_options from “Domain Name” to “https://DOMAIN NAME”.

Hope this helps took me hours to figure it out.